# pandas from datetime64[ns] to object (python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have the code show below, where, after to convert the column `closingdate` from `object` to `datetime` an operate with it,and after to created a new column named 'start' with the results, I need to converted this column `start` from `datetime` to `object` , before to convert it to json.

If anyone can help I will highly appreciate it.Thanks in advance.

```
initial_data = sql(query1)
initial_data['closingdate'] = pd.to_datetime(initial_data.closingdate)

initial_data['start']=pd.to_datetime(initial_data.closingdate)+pd.to_timedelta(pd.np.ceil(initial_data.tenor1),unit='D')

initial_data=initial_data[['dealid','title','tranch_structure','start']]
initial_data['start']=pd.to_str(initial_data.start)


initial_data =initial_data.to_json(orient='table')
```

Comment: Please try to format your question respecting the 4 spaces ident for your code part, this will make your question much more readable.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a specific format , let's say 'YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS', you could consider the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
def convert_datetime(dt):
    return datetime.strftime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M-%S')

df['timestamps']= df ['timestamps'].apply(convert_datetime)
```